# Unflattening a list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, iteration

Problem:

> Write a function named "unflatten" which takes a list as an argument
> and constructs a nested list.
>
> The format of the argument list is as follows:
>
> An integer item indicates a start of a nested list Non-integer items
> will be the content of the nested list For instance,
>
> `[2, 'a', 3, 'b', 'c', 'd']` is converted to `['a', ['b', 'c', 'd']]` The
> first number, 2, indicates that the upper list will contain 2 items.
> `'a'` is the first item of this upper list. The number 3 indicates a
> start of a new sub-list which contains 3 items.

Sample Run:

```
>>> unflatten([2, 'x', 'y'])
['x', 'y']
>>> unflatten([ 3, "a", "b", 3, "t", "y", "u" ])
['a', 'b', ['t', 'y', 'u']]
>>> unflatten([ 4, "a", "b", 3, "c", "d", 2, "x", "y", 2, "w" , 3, "t", "y", "u" ])
['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['x', 'y']], ['w', ['t', 'y', 'u']]]
```

I have done a simple recursion. Here is my code:

```
def unflatten(LIST):
    if not len(LIST):
       return []
    elif isinstance(LIST[0], int):
        return [unflatten(LIST[1:])]
    else:
        return [LIST[0]]  + unflatten(LIST[1:])


>>> unflatten([ 4, "a", "b", 3, "c", "d", 2, "x", "y", 2, "w" , 3, "t", "y", "u" ])
[['a', 'b', ['c', 'd', ['x', 'y', ['w', ['t', 'y', 'u']]]]]]
```

Now as you can see, lengths of lists are not controlled in my basic recursion, so it simply ends all the lists at the end.

I don't know how I can track the lengths recursively, or maybe iteratively. I'd be glad if you suggest a way doing this without importing any modules.

Comment: You have to take into account that if `isinstance(LIST[0], int)` then you have `LIST[0]` elements next. You could use a helper function, `unflatten(l)` can call `unflatten_bis(l[1:],l[0])` and `unflatten_bis` will do all the work. (just a suggestion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to keep track of the position is by returning it. In the code below I use a helper function that returns the partially-built unflattened list as well as the current index in the flattened list.

```
def unflatten(l):
  def helper(l, start):
    if isinstance(l[start], int):
      ret = []
      start += 1
      for _ in range(l[start - 1]):
        sub, start = helper(l, start)
        ret.append(sub)
      return ret, start
    else:
      return l[start], start + 1
  return helper(l, 0)[0]

print unflatten([2, 'x', 'y'])
print unflatten([ 3, "a", "b", 3, "t", "y", "u" ])
print unflatten([ 4, "a", "b", 3, "c", "d", 2, "x", "y", 2, "w" , 3, "t", "y", "u" ])
```