# Nest a flat list based on an arbitrary criterion

Tags: python, list

I have a flat list of unique objects, some of which may share a given attribute with others. I wish to create a nested list-of-lists, with objects grouped by the given attribute. As a minimal example, given the following list:

```
>>> flat = ["Shoes", "pants", "shirt", "tie", "jacket", "hat"]
```

I might want to group it by length, eg:

```
>>> nest_by_length(flat)
[['tie', 'hat'], ['shoes', 'pants', 'shirt'], ['jacket']]
```

I've seen a couple of [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27620855/unflattening-a-list-in-python) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916209/how-to-build-a-nested-list-from-a-flat-one-in-python) and [suggestions](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577061-nest-a-flat-list/). However, in all of these cases, the nesting is based on the ordering of the input list. In my case, the ordering of the input list is completely unpredictable, as is the number of sub-lists for the output and the number of items per sub-list.

Is there a standard function or idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A common idiom for an existing list is to use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby

flat = ["Shoes", "pants", "shirt", "tie", "jacket", "hat"]

result=[]
for k, g in groupby(sorted(flat, key=len), key=len):
    result.append(list(g))

print result
```

Or, more tersely:

```
[list(g) for _,g in groupby(sorted(flat, key=len), key=len)]
```

Prints:

```
[['tie', 'hat'], ['Shoes', 'pants', 'shirt'], ['jacket']]
```

Input to `groupby` is grouped into groups based on the changing value of output of the key function, in this case `len`. Generally, you need to preorder the list based on the same key function, so the `sorted` function is called first.

If your source list is not complete yet, or not sortable based on the criteria (or you would just prefer another option), create a dict that maps your criteria to a unique key value:

```
groups={}
for e in flat:
    groups.setdefault(len(e), []).append(e)

print groups    
# {5: ['Shoes', 'pants', 'shirt'], 3: ['tie', 'hat'], 6: ['jacket']}
```

You can also use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) rather than setdefault with the arbitrary key value:

```
from collections import defaultdict
groups=defaultdict(list)
for e in flat:
    groups[len(e)].append(e)  
# groups=defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {5: ['Shoes', 'pants', 'shirt'], 3: ['tie', 'hat'], 6: ['jacket']})
```

In either case, then you can create the nested list from that:

```
>>> [groups[k] for k in sorted(groups.keys())] 
[['tie', 'hat'], ['Shoes', 'pants', 'shirt'], ['jacket']]
```

Comment: I appreciate your thoroughness. I suspected there would be some function like groupby that I didn't know, but the dictionary trick is just clever. Thanks!